# Why doesn't Pydev find Django?

Tags: python, django, pydev

I have Django installed. I also have django-admin.py in my python-2.7 folder. I can `import django` using my Python shell (DreamPie). But I can't create a new Django project in Pydev. When trying to create a new Pydev Django Project (choosing python2.7 as the interpreter) I receive the following error message:

[image: Django not found]

I went to the link in the message and I have all the pre-requisite to getting started in Django: Django is installed and `import django` properly works (in the shell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse:

Window --> Preferences --> Interpreter - Python.

Make sure to choose Python2.7 as the interpreter.

Now, click New Folder. Browse to find the path to django (in this case: *C:\Django-1.2.5\django*).

[image: preferences]

OK --> Apply --> OK.

That's it. You can create a new Django project.

Comment: this seemed to work for me, except I had to combine it with the tips of the previous comments. Instead of adding "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django" i added only "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"

also, I had to add it for all version of python, not just 2.7 (in my case, that was 3.3 + 2.7). happy hunting

Answer (score 3):

What helped me (adjust dir and file names according your installation):

I created copy of file *Django-1.3-py2.7.egg-info* from `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\` in the same folder with extender **.egg*.

Then, in Eclipse dialog

```
Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter-Python
```

I used buton *New Egg/Zip(s)* in order to add this newly created file to System PYTHONPATH list.

This way Eclipse found Django.

Answer (score 1):

### I refer to [Fabio Zadroznys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110451/fabio-zadrozny)  answer which should work for all of you.

> Probably the PYTHONPATH configured in your interpreter is not correct...
>
> I.e.: if you have a structure with
>
> /my/path/django 
> /my/path/django/**init**.py
>
> you have to make sure that
>
> /my/path
>
> is added to the PYTHONPATH (**and /my/path/django is NOT!!!**)
>
> Another thing to note is that right after installing Django, you just have to do a refresh >in your interpreter so that it's recognized (go to the interpreter preferences page, press >'apply' and choose the interpreters to be re-analyzed -- there are already plans to make >this automatic in one of the upcoming releases, but right now you have to do that manually >because the interpreter is analyzed when you configure it and 'set in stone').

**LINK:** 
[pydev does not recognize django installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749871/pydev-does-not-recognize-django-installation)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow any python version. But in your case Django is not installed globally.

Requirement is you need to have Django installed in system.

For checking the django is installed or not

open CMD / terminal (Assuming that Python is already installed)

```
$ python

$ import django

$ django.VERSION
```

You can see the output like this. Here I am using Django 3.1

```
(3, 1, 0, 'final', 0)
```

Then in the Preferences --> Interpreter - Python --> Click new and add the location where python.exe or Python application resides. Make sure you are naming the Interpreter appropriately for future reference.

Then restart the eclipse and go to New --> Other --> PyDev --> PyDev Django Project

1. Name your project
2. Select the Interpreter that you previously created from the drop down.

The above fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

not working for me.  the attached screensnap shows that django is importable from the pydev shell, and that the path to it is in pydev's SYSTEMPATH.

[image]

(since folks have mentioned virtualenv in other questions, i'll mention this is occuring within a virtualbox but i don't think that matters?)

Answer (score -1):

It needs to be in the PATH or in the /usr/bin

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand. What needs to be where? What file do I need to copy to which location?

Comment: I'm on Windows. Just solved the problem and answered to my own question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JakeKalstad Doesn't sound like you read the question entirely.